# Venn diagrams show + - = underneath

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\centering
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillA \fillB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
        $P(A \cup B)  $
\hfill
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillA 
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
         $P(A) \ \ $
\hfill
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
        $P(B) \ \ $
\hfill
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillACapB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
         $P(A \cap B)$
\end{multicols}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It produces this picture:

[image]

I want to add `=` between the captions of the first and second images; `+` between the captions of the second and third; and `-` between the third and fourth.

That is, the caption should read: P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B).

I want the symbols to align between each figure. That is, there is white space between the first two images and I want the = sign under that white space, in line with the caption. Same idea for the + and -.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible solutions using `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c@{}c@{}}c}
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillA \fillB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
        &&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillA 
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
&&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
&&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillACapB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}\\

$P(A \cup B)  $ & = & $P(A) \ \ $ & + & $P(B) \ \ $ & - & $P(A \cap B)$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillA \fillB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
        &&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillA 
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
&&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
&&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillACapB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}\\

$P(A \cup B)  $ & = & $P(A) \ \ $ & + & $P(B) \ \ $ & - & $P(A \cap B)$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```